# Get all the uid of the tree nodes

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

I am using kendo treeview. I need to get all the datasource with all the uid of all nodes (not just of those showing but also the collapsed ones).
I use this way to get the datasource :

`dataSource = treeElement.data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data()`

And I get an object with only the current showing nodes there. I can see that at :

```
treeElement.data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.options.data
```

all the nodes show but not their uid. It's just an array of my data.

Any suggestion how to achieve this? Again I need an object with all the nodes and their uid that kendo uses.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes to this question. I solved it by setting `loadOnDemand: false` to the kendoTreeView configuration